# Google reCaptcha V2 (Invisible) only fires once

Tags: javascript, security, recaptcha

today i tried to implement Google ReCAPTCHA V2 in ivisible mode. In the documentation, they showed, how to use it.

```
<button class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="your_site_key" data-callback='onSubmit'>Submit</button>
```

I tried this solution, but the "onSubmit" function only gots called once. After that, the Button simply does nothing...

Its there a way to fix that Issue without reloading the page?

Thanks,

Sascha

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have hit the same problem today. Looks like they've changed their API recently.

I fixed this problem by adding `grecaptcha.reset();` in the end of the **onSubmit** function. The problem is that captcha doesn't call back anymore when it is triggered once, so it needs to be [reloaded](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#js_api).